# Magento 2 checkout page custom dropdown field selected value not showing

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, custom, knockoutjs

I have added dropdown custom field on checkout page with custom values.  It's working fine but when i move to next step it doesn't work.

If i add a text field and click next console shows the input field value but if I change it to select then it doesn't even field name in a console.  What could be the issue?

```
  <?php
   namespace Jack\CheckoutAdditionalField\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


 class LayoutProcessor
  {
/**
 * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
 * @param array $jsLayout
 * @return array
 */
public function afterProcess(
    \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
    array  $jsLayout
) {
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['delivery_date'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/date',
            'options' => [],
            'id' => 'delivery-date'
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_date',
        'label' => 'Delivery Date',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 250,
        'id' => 'delivery-date'
    ];

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
    ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['drop_down'] = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
            'id' => 'drop-down',
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.drop_down',
        'label' => 'Drop Down',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'visible' => true,
        'validation' => [],
        'sortOrder' => 251,
        'id' => 'drop-down',
        'options' => [
            [
                'value' => '',
                'label' => 'Please Select',
            ],
            [
                'value' => '1',
                'label' => 'First Option',
            ]
        ]
    ];

    return $jsLayout;
}
```

}

When i move to next step on payment method then field and it's value is not showing in console if i will add text field then it will show posted value in console.

Need help why select dropdown value not showing in console?  Also, how can i save this value to show in order information.

Comment: Did you get the solution ?

Comment: No,   i didn't. Lost the client because of that.

Comment: I have added option again inside the config....somehow thats work for me

Comment: hi @jack let me know whether you got solution for this? can you please post the answer

Comment: Hi,  Yes got solution for this

Comment: https://github.com/pmclain/module-twilio   Download this extension. It's twilo extension which adds the dropdown option on checkout page.  just grab that code and modify it as per your need.  I did same.